# How to determine the XPATH of Android UI elements. Selenium + Appium

Tags: android, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am currently working on automating an android application using Appium and Selenium and have run into some problems with locating elements by ID. I want to use XPATH but do not know how to get the XPATH of android UI elements. Does anyone know how to determine the XPATH of an element or know of a tool that can do this work quickly? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use android sdk tool - uiautomatorviewer( https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) it's like appium inspector, but work better for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
com.android2.calculator3:id/digit8
```

For Elements with id

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.testapp:id/txtLogin"))
```

For Elements with class

```
android.widget.EditText[@index=0]
```

Syntax

```
{ClassName}[@{anyAttributeName}={valueOfAttribute}]
```

Code

```
driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));//will return ARRAY
```

Comment: You should use UIautomatiorviewer to find the exact element
or layout of your application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can figure out the xpath. First get the page source from the application. This will be in xml format. Then copy the source to a xpath tester website like [xpath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath). Then create the xpath and check if it works. This is assuming you already know how to create xpaths.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to use xpath tester?

Answer (score 1):

[**Appium's client comes with an Inspector tool!**](https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-exe#inspector--recorder)
This will tell you the xpath of whatever element you're interested in

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the source code:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-view-source-in-the-android-browser

Then figuring out the xpath becomes easier from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIAutomatorviewer utility in Android SDK to get the required locator. Go to your Android SDK installation's 'tools' folder and trigger uiautomatorviewer.bat file. From there, you can locate app elements.

Visit this link which shows how to use it.

http://www.testingdiaries.com/locate-android-app-elements/

Comment: Please add some info from linked page to your answer, because if the link stops working, your answer will be almost worthless

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer options in your phone and Connect your phone and invoke the chrome inspector for android devices( type -- about:inspect in chrome ) your device will be displayed.

Just click on the Inspect button & the screen in mobile will be displayed.
You are provided with the application and the complete DOM structure.. Make your own XPATH from that.

Answer (score -1):

You could use it like this:

```
WebElement btn_yes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Yes']"));
```